# Does Qt only load widgets that fit on the window?

Tags: image, qt, loading

I was wondering why image loading in Qt appears to be so much faster than in a game I'm working on.

I've created a simple test app that loads 70 500x500 PNG images using `QPixmap` and then displays these in 70 `QLabel`s in a `QVBoxLayout`. It opens nearly instanteous, while my game takes one or two seconds to load these using libpng.

Not all labels are visible in the window - only two in fact - so I'm wondering: Does Qt perhaps only load images that are actually used and visible on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they a loaded as soon as appropriate QPixmap constructor called. 70 500x500 png is not that much to spend several seconds on loading, try to profile your algorithms

Comment: It was actually ~100 images, not 70. I looked at how long the image loading is taking in Qt, and it turns out it actually takes ~1.7 seconds, which is even slower than my game (~1.2 seconds). I didn't notice because they only show the window after all images are loaded...